# Find angle of ABC given position vector

Tags: vector-spaces

Point A, B and C have position vector -2i+3j, i-3j and 4i+2j respectively. Find the angle ABC.

Can I just convert for example -2i + 3j to (-2, 3)?

Comment: yes${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the angle between them using cross products.

$$\vec{u}=A-B=-3\hat{i}+6\hat{j}\\
\vec{v}=C-B=3\hat{i}+5\hat{j}$$

$$|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\sin(\theta)=|\vec{u}\times\vec{v}|$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle $\angle{ABC}$.

Comment: if the question change to find the angel of BAC. Just change v = c- b to v = c - a?

Comment: @user Then it's $\vec{v}=C-A$ and $\vec{u}=B-A$. By the way there was a typo in my answer, I had $B-A$, but it should be $A-B$.

Answer (score 0):

find vector $BA$ and $BC$ then,
$$\theta =\operatorname{arccos}(\frac{BA.BC}{|BA||BC|})$$